# Capturing output messages during flyway migration

Tags: migration, stdout, message, flyway

I would like to capture the messages logged by SQLServerDbSupport and DBMigrate during a migration. Calling flyway.migrate does the migration, but it is not always obvious what actions were applied. I am hoping to capture this to determine what changes, if any were applied.

I already tried setting STDOUT to a ByteArrayOutputStream but that didn't work, presumably as the logger is initialised before the re-direction.

What other options are there to obtain the output messages ?

Answer (score 0):

All you have to do is configure whatever logging framework you use to achieve this. No need to reassign stdout.

Comment: Any pointers on how to do this. Ideally I would like to capture the output form multiple concurrent runs, with each output going to it's own stream.

Answer (score 0):

While this suggestion is great I am not sure how it addresses the need to capture the output from one migration only, while another migration is running. Do you have an example of a logger configuration which deal with individual migration in a concurrent scenario /